# Is it possible to apply MahApps’s TextBoxHelper to a ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, mahapps.metro

I’m building a WPF application in which there’s a `TextBox`. To apply rounded corners to it, [here](https://parallelcodes.com/wpf-textbox-rounded-corners-border/) I read that I need to create a specific style using a `ScrollViewer` inside a `Border`. So far so good, but I want to apply the funcionalities of MahApps’ `TextBoxHelper` class, which lets you use stuff like:

```
<TextBox controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="I’m a watermark"/>
```

to display a watermark inside the `TextBox`. The problem is that I don’t understand how to combine the style (using the advices in the article I linked to) with MahApps. I tried something like:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="myKey">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  ctrl:TextboxHelper.Watermark="true"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but the watermark doesn’t show.

Comment: How confident are you on customising wpf control templates? And. How much do you like rounded corners on textboxes?  Personally, I find them rather impractical BTW.

Comment: Unfortunatel, I have to. I’m almost no confident.

Comment: How about mahapps. Did you want just the helper because you don't know how to do a watermark or are you using the theme everywhere?

Comment: I’m working on an already existing project. They use just the helper, and they told me to use that to display the watermark and the clear button to reset the box.